# wordpress: how to force a form fill before going to a page?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am building a wordpress site with this requirement: when the user attempts to navigate to certain pages, they will be forced to fill out a small form (enter their email address) before they can get to the desired page.

On a standalone site, I'd do it like this: on each "protected" page, I'd look for a cookie named "email". If this cookie doesn't exist, redirect to an email capture page, along with a url parameter indicating the page to go to after they enter their email. The email form would call a PHP script that would set the "email" cookie, then redirect to the desired page

How to do this in wordpress? Would I create my cookie testing code in a template and assign that to the protected pages?

Answer (score 0):

Create a template and page for your php code and when user try to navigate to protected pages check for cookie if doesnt exist go to email page (instead it would be fine if the form appears in a pop up window).There when you get the email onsubmit use ajax to go create cookie from php page and once the cookie is set the navigation should take place .you should create a template for the php page ,and give the page id in ajax code 
I hope this is what u r looking for.